# Foursquare Venues: Combing Results: Is this approach allowed for missing results?

Tags: foursquare

I plan to use Foursquare Venues to help users fill up a form about the location of the event that they would be creating on our website.

However, sometimes the event location is not present or unaccurate in the foursquare's database. In this scenario we are planning to ask user to manually enter the event location information which would we would save in our own database.

Next time a user enters a location, we would give them suggestions by combining the results from our database and Foursquares.

The question I have is: **is this allowed and accepted by the Foursquare api usage policy**? Thanks.

--
a demo of how I am using Foursquare Venues currently: http://karanverma.info/Ingressos/venues.html

Comment: Can anyone help with answering this question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed. See [foursquare Policies](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community) page for more information.

They do **not** allow merging of data from their database and google, but they allow you to extend with data of your own.

That link contains all the different usage policies information, not just for the venues database, but generally if you have a more specific question you should just ask them directly ([link for their support page](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/support))